# can't join kubernetes cluster; connection refused

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, vagrant

I am getting the following error when I try to join the cluster :

```
[preflight] running pre-flight checks
    [WARNING RequiredIPVSKernelModulesAvailable]: the IPVS proxier will not be used, because the following required kernel modules are not loaded: [ip_vs_rr ip_vs_wrr ip_vs_sh ip_vs] or no builtin kernel ipvs support: map[ip_vs_sh:{} nf_conntrack_ipv4:{} ip_vs:{} ip_vs_rr:{} ip_vs_wrr:{}]
you can solve this problem with following methods:
 1. Run 'modprobe -- ' to load missing kernel modules;
2. Provide the missing builtin kernel ipvs support

I0822 12:21:25.433590   14413 kernel_validator.go:81] Validating kernel version
I0822 12:21:25.433667   14413 kernel_validator.go:96] Validating kernel config
[discovery] Trying to connect to API Server "10.0.2.15:6443"
[discovery] Created cluster-info discovery client, requesting info from "https://10.0.2.15:6443"
[discovery] Failed to request cluster info, will try again: [Get https://10.0.2.15:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-public/configmaps/cluster-info: dial tcp 10.0.2.15:6443: connect: connection refused]
[discovery] Failed to request cluster info, will try again: [Get https://10.0.2.15:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-public/configmaps/cluster-info: dial tcp 10.0.2.15:6443: connect: connection refused
```

I used this command to initialize the master :

```
$ sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16 –-apiserver-advertise-address=192.168.1.180 --kubernetes-version stable-1.11
```

Join command to run in slave node is :

```
sudo kubeadm join 10.0.2.15:6443 --token 0ux20u.8atg4nwhaup80qpi --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:6cf4f16530ae7e28fba67ca7419b047e8ff36bb8e8212c9b3164eff8cad021c6
```

I can't ping the master node at IP 10.0.2.15.

But i can successfully ping at IP: 192.168.2.180 , which is set as the static ip for public network in Vagrantfile of the master VM.

I tried setting private network Ip,bridge for public network in vagrant file.But none of them worked.

On the same machine I'm using:

docker version 1.13.1 and 
k8s version 1.11

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please post the `Vagrantfile`

Comment: You are using the wrong interface. Run `ip addr` instead of `eth0` use `eth1`.